# Gnome on screen keyboard when in tablet mode

Tags: gnome, keyboard, tablet

Just installed Ubuntu 22.04. I have a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga 3rd and cannot get the on screen keyboard to show up consistently (e.g. as in an Android phone). When I enable the screen keyboard in the accessibility settings and switch to "tablet mode", it shows up only on the activities search box. But if I click on any other app requiring text input (e.g. Firefox search bar, Telegram, whatever) it does not show up. This makes the the tablet mode quite unusable. Is there a fix for this?